# Need to Remove Show/Hide Links Above Menus

Tags: 8

How do I remove the Show Hide links above the menus?  See the example

[image]

I'm using Drupal 8 and Mayo theme.

Comment: You'll need to sub theme and hide with CSS the `.menu-toggle` attribute.

Comment: Seems like you have broken JS or CSS in your theme.